# Marklogic Dialect support in Hibernate OGM

Tags: hibernate, marklogic, hibernate-ogm

Although Marklogic is having api like optic to query against the marklogic database, I am really curious to know whether we are having marklogic support in hibernate.

Does hibernate ogm support marklogic database?

Comment: I don't have any direct experience, but looks like you should be able to plug in via JDBC over the MarkLogic SQL interface: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/marklogic-jdbc-hibernate.rst